# Keep array attributes in a session

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, session

I have this javascript function:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' && c[i].checked==true){
        booked_seats[count]=c[i].id;
        c[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#F00";

        count++;

    }
}
```

which is called when the Submit button is clicked. I want the c[] array to be kept in a session, so when the page is refreshed the changes remain (the change of color in specific cells of the table and the checked boxes). How exactly can I accomplish that?

Comment: If you just care about keeping the data on the client side, you can use cookies or local storage. If you need the data on the server side, you need to sent it there with request, either directly or via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to send these parameters along with the rest of the form to the server, then to put them back in the form with inline PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achive this

- HTML5 supports a local storage where you can store all you want. I.e [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)
- You could store the values in cookies which are accessible for php and javascript
- You could send your changes to the server(i.e. ajax) and restore them after page refresh

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest attaching the needed data to form elements (hidden or not) and checking for values when the page loads:

```
if ($_GET["x"])
$x = $_GET["x"];

if ($_GET["y"])
$x = $_GET["y"];
```

This may be more efficient using a `foreach`, but now place $x back where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to store array information in a cookie is by using jQuery along with the Cookie plugin.

Here's the page with the source code and example usage - http://code.google.com/p/cookies/

Also, here's another question on Stackoverflow which answers your problem: [How to store an array in a JavaScript cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408463/how-to-store-an-array-in-a-javascript-cookie)