# Store the history list of the url and access previous and next url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs and jquery. I want to store the history list of url manually so that I can access the url as per as need and chould go foreward and backward accordingly. I have already used `document.referrer` and `window.history.back()` but I cannot fetch the url I need.

So please tell me a way so that I can fetch it manually and can store it in a array or somethhing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried javascript cookies?

Comment: `No, But please tell me the way so that I can try.`

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408463/how-to-store-an-array-in-a-javascript-cookie

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can access the browser history list directly from the `window.history` object.

If you really needs to do this, it can be tricky and ugly.

For sinlge page app which use url hash to switch application state，you can listen to the `hashchange` event and push the hash into an array:

```
var history = [];
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    history.push(location.hash);
});
```

For multi-page app, maybe you could listen to the `onunload` event, and write the current url into a cookie. You have to add the code to every page you have; very unelegant.

If the user navigate to a page that you don't own, then you have no way to record that part of history.

You mentioned in your question that you use angularjs. Normaly when you use these mvx frameworks, you don't deal with browser history directly, you deal with the application route.
Maybe you should take a look at the angularjs $route doc and see if this meets your need.

[angularjs $route doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route)

[angularjs tutorial that mentions how to use $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Answer (score 1):

My application is in this way to record all routing .

```
var angularAdmin = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

angularAdmin.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.history = [];
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $rootScope.history.push($location.$$path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**$route , $location** angular services are your friend.

**$location.absUrl();**

**$routeChangeSuccess** event good place to capture route changes if you are using angular's default routing

Comment: `It would be great if you can provide me with some tutorials of this`