# Saving multiple selected items on a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to save user selected items on a cookie that way when they navigate on another page or refresh the page their preference is being saved. The selected item are also being clone on a different DOM element, i'm not sure if i'm doing it compliantly. At the moment, I can only save one item, I wanted to be able to save multiple items.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var cookieName = 'franchiseSelected',
        cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};

    $('input[name="' + $.cookie(cookieName) + '"]').attr("checked","checked").parent('li').clone().appendTo("#selected_items");

    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        // $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).removeClass("selectedLanguage");
        $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr('value'), cookieOptions);
        $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("selectedLanguage");
        $(this).parent('li').clone().appendTo("#selected_items")
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Select Item</h2>
<ul class="items">

    <li> <input name="dog" value="dog" type="checkbox" /> <span>Dog</span> </li>   
    <li> <input name="cat" value="cat" type="checkbox" /> <span>Cat</span> </li>   
    <li> <input name="bird" value="bird" type="checkbox" /> <span>Bird</span> </li>   
    <li> <input name="donkey" value="donkey" type="checkbox" /> <span>Donkey</span> </li>   

</ul>

<br>
<h2>Selected Items</h2>
<ul id="selected_items"></ul>
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh22C/

Comment: you need to store an array inside your cookie and then call the array items whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this by storing more values in one cookie (using an array or something), or by using multiple cookies with different values.

This is how to store/get an array in/from cookies: [Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408463/how-to-store-an-array-in-a-javascript-cookie)